# Selenium webdriver not opening websites in default chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried selenium webdriver in Python and it works fine. But when I try to open default chrome profile it doesn't open the websites.

The code is

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-
dir=/Users/prajwal/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
capability = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capability["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capability, 
chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

The window opens in this case. But it doesnt open the website. However, it works fine if I remove

```
chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-
dir=/Users/prajwal/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Could be the space in the file path? Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Mac. No it's not because of space. Its opening the window. But not opening the websites.

Comment: @Prajwal Did you get the solution?

Comment: @arqam The thing is that, when the chrome browser instance is not opened with the default profile, it opens the websites. I suggest you to close the Chrome browser and then run the python script, then it opens the websites.